# EWS API: how to retrieve modification date for an attachment

Tags: exchangewebservices

I want to retrieve an attachment from EWS API. Unfortunately GetAttachment by default does not return Modification Date for an attachment.

My EWS API SOAP request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <soap:Envelope
            xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
            xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <soap:Header>
                <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
                <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
                    <t:ConnectingSID>
                        <t:PrimarySmtpAddress>%1%</t:PrimarySmtpAddress>
                    </t:ConnectingSID>
                </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
            </soap:Header>
            <soap:Body>
                <m:GetAttachment>
                    <m:AttachmentShape />
                    <m:AttachmentIds>
                        <t:AttachmentId Id="%2%" />
                    </m:AttachmentIds>
                </m:GetAttachment>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
```

Is it possible to get Modifitation Date from EWS API? How can I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You have the correct `GetAttachment` operation, but firstly you need to get the message and the attachment collection to get the `AttachmentId` of the attachment to retrieve.

Use the `GetItem` operation to do this. The `GetItemResponse` message will then include the `LastModifiedTime` property your looking for.

See [Get an attachment from an email by using EWS](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-developer-exchange-docs/blob/master/docs/exchange-web-services/how-to-get-attachments-by-using-ews-in-exchange.md#get-an-attachment-from-an-email-by-using-ews)

Comment: Can you please provide an example how should I properly set this property in my request from above? Thanks